# Change name and Bulk Update Joomla / Virtuemart Product Type Parameters

Tags: parameters, types, joomla, product, virtuemart

I am working with a Joomla / Virtuemart install and ran into a problem when trying to update Product Type Parameters.

I have a Product Type with `Multiple Values` as the Parameter type.  I then have a list of possible values like so: `Type A;Type B;Type C`.

I need to change the names of some of these values.  For example, let's say I want to change `Type B` to `Type X`.  I can easily change that in the `Possible values` field, but all of the products that are currently assigned to `Type B` are not assigned to `Type X` upon the change.  So the newly renamed `Type X` is empty.

Is there any way I can bulk update or change all of the products assigned to `Type B` to become `Type X`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have four solutions:

1. Modify the category name if all the products in that category are to be affected (e.g. change category name `type b` to `type x`).
2. Use the virtuemart plugin [Bulk Product Type and Product Parameter Manager](http://www.ledgloeilamp.nl/VirtueMart-Extensions-Modules/Bulk-Product-Type-and-Product-Parameter-Manager/productdetails.tpl.htm).
3. Download your mysql files for the involved database tables and alter them manually.
4. Do it manually from inside virtuemart (especially if the items being changed are not many).

Answer (score 2):

ReReplacer By Nonumber is an excellent tool for replacing or swapping things out... basically an easy interface for Joomla Database find and replace.